# Quote in a string in python

Tags: python, shell, sed

I am trying to write a shell script into a python script to translate the syntax of a .sql file.

I have written this :

```
import os
sqlFile = raw_input("Type the name of your .sql file: ")

os.system('dos2unix '+ sqlFile)    
os.system(""" sed -i 's/dbo//g' """ + sqlFile)
```

And I have this error :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
```

I have tried many things, with single ", double "", also with \' etc... but it doesn't work and I was sceptic about the \' because if I need this character into the shell script it would be difficult to differentiate.... Nevermind it didn't work.
I am pretty sure someone has the solution but every single solution I tried from the net didn't work.

Thank you for your help and your time !

Comment: Have you tried `'sed -i "s/dbo//g"'`?

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì it seems to be a mistake in the syntax of the sed command finally (in another one because I have nine sed commands). Because I tried with other sed commands and it works, so the problem I think is the sed ! Thank you :)

Comment: I'd really recommend to use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for dealing with external program calls instead of raw `system` calls.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @languitar
Then, my problem is solved and it wasn't because of the quotes but because of a bad sed syntax in one of my nine sed commands. So I don't know if I have to change or delete the post.

Comment: Someone can provide the respective comment that helped as an answer, which you can accept.